How to pass a pointer to multiple functions
I'm currently in the process of making my code work for STM32s through a code sample I found online: https://www.exploreembedded.com/wiki/Interfacing_Gas_Sensor_(MQ2)_With_AVR involving an MQ2 gas sensor. I am using a STM32F030F4P6 and the STM32CubeIDE.
My goal is to take ADC readings and use them in functions outside of the main. I created a pointer called StoreADCval and set it equal to the address of ADCval. I want to call this address each time in the separate functions I have outside of the main but I'm not sure if I'm doing it the right way. In the three float functions outside of the main, I called the pointer using uint_16t *StoreADCval to attempt to gather the ADC channel data from the main and use it in the function.
My code can be seen below:
#include "main.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>


ADC_HandleTypeDef hadc1;

UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;


uint16_t ADCval;
char msg [100];
float LPGCurve[3]  = {2.3,0.20,-0.45};
float SmokeCurve[3] ={2.3,0.53,-0.43};
float Ro =  10;
#define LPG  (0)                     //Gas identity number macro
#define Smoke (1)                    //Smoke identity number macro
#define Rl_Value (10)                //Load resistor on MQ2 board macro
#define Ro_Clean_Air_Factor (9.83)   //(Sensor resistance in clean air)/Ro macro
float SensorCalibration(ADCval);

int GetPercentage(float rs_ro_ratio, float *pcurve);
int GetGasPercentage(float rs_ro_ratio, int gas_id);
float ReadSensor(ADCval);
float ResistanceCalculation(ADCval);
float SensorCalibration(ADCval);


void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_ADC1_Init(void);
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void);

int main(void)
{


  HAL_Init();


  SystemClock_Config();


  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_ADC1_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();


  sprintf(msg, "Calibrating Sensor... \r\n");
  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t*)msg, strlen(msg), HAL_MAX_DELAY);
  Ro = SensorCalibration();



  sprintf(msg, "Calibrating is complete \r\n");
  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t*)msg, strlen(msg), HAL_MAX_DELAY);
  sprintf(msg, "Ro: %0.5fkohm \r\n", Ro);
  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t*)msg, strlen(msg), HAL_MAX_DELAY);


  while (1)
  {
       HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc1);
       ADCval = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1);
       HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc1, 100);
       ADCval = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1);

       sprintf(msg,"%hu", ADCval);
       HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t*)msg, strlen(msg), HAL_MAX_DELAY);

       sprintf(msg, "   LPG: %3d ppm",GetGasPercentage(ReadSensor()/Ro, LPG));
       HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t*)msg, strlen(msg), HAL_MAX_DELAY);

       sprintf(msg, " Smoke: %3d ppm \n\r",GetGasPercentage(ReadSensor()/Ro, Smoke));
       HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t*)msg, strlen(msg), HAL_MAX_DELAY);

       HAL_Delay(100);
  }

}

float ResistanceCalculation(ADCval)
{
 return ( ((float)Rl_Value*(4095-ADCval)/ ADCval));
}

float SensorCalibration(ADCval)
{
 int i;
 float val=0;

 for (i=0;i<50;i++) {

 val += ResistanceCalculation(ADCval);
 HAL_Delay(500);

}
 val = val/50;
 val = val/Ro_Clean_Air_Factor;
 return val;
}

float ReadSensor(ADCval)
{
  int i;
  float rs=0;

  for (i=0;i<5;i++) {

  rs += ResistanceCalculation(ADCval);
  HAL_Delay(50);                                   //0.5 sec delay
 }
  rs = rs/5;
  return rs;
}

int GetGasPercentage(float rs_ro_ratio, int gas_id)
{
  if ( gas_id == LPG ) {
  return GetPercentage(rs_ro_ratio,LPGCurve);

  } else if ( gas_id == Smoke ) {
  return GetPercentage(rs_ro_ratio,SmokeCurve);
  }

  return 0;
}


int  GetPercentage(float rs_ro_ratio, float *pcurve)
{
 return (pow(10,( ((log10(rs_ro_ratio)-pcurve[1])/pcurve[2]) + pcurve[0])));
}



I'm not sure what you are asking. The pointer doesn't seem to fill any purpose, if that's the question.

@Lundin I want to take the ADC value I'm storing from the main and use it in multiple functions. I realized I would have to do this through a pointer but not sure how to grab the ADC value from the main and use it In the functions.

float something = ResistanceCalculation(&ADCval); for example. Basic C stuff not really related to microcontroller programming.

Btw you need to make an effort of intending your code so that it turns readable. Had you posted something like this in a professional code review context, you would have been instantly dismissed.

@Lundin edited the code, so I guess something like this should be posted on stack overflow instead of stack exchange.

Why even want to pass the function a pointer that points to the variable you need; if you don't need to write the variable contents? Why can't you just pass the data as a parameter to function? Or since it is a global variable just read it?

I don't find anything named StoreADCval in the code

@pipe I changed the code to use a global variable instead, I thought I needed a pointer but it turns out I don’t so now I’m calling the variable in each function

I’m voting to close this question because it's about software


I don't see anywhere in the code where a pointer is required. Just use a global variable.

Global variables (or pointers) can already be accessed inside of functions. You don't need to pass an argument for this.

When you create a function argument with the same name as a global, it creates a second (totally independent) variable. So now within the function namespace you've got 2 variables with the same name. The local name (the argument variable) masks the global name, so you can no longer access the global one. There's rarely any reason to do this. You've done this in your code.



I've edited my code (which can be seen above), but I'm still getting 0ppm for my output, not sure if I called the global variable correctly each time in my function, clearly I'm missing something but I'm not sure what.

Try setting up the debugger and stepping through the code.
